# How to add www to url and redirect?

Tags: c#, web-applications, response.redirect

How can I response redirect from http://domain.com to http://www.domain.com?
Code, not Web.config, which doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:  [How to 301 Redirect Non-WWW to WWW URLs](http://www.stepforth.com/resources/web-marketing-knowledgebase/non-www-redirect)

Comment: You're answers need to be a little more informative and verbose, or they'll get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are hosting in IIS, then you can set up a HTTP redirect.

[IIS6 Redirects](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)

[IIS7 Redirects](http://www.trainsignaltraining.com/windows-server-2008-http-redirection/2008-03-27/)

[Information about 301 redirects](http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php)

**EDIT**

You could add the following to your Page_Load method:

```
// Check if page is running under theperfectfajita.com. If not redirect ...
if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.Contains("localhost"))
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.CompareTo("domain.com") != 0)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://www.domain.com" + Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a 301 redirect to the correct url. Something like this;

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
Response.RedirectLocation = "http://www.domain.com";
```

Comment: because its the same page it keeps looping

Comment: Can you show us the code of how you implemented it now? Try adding a return null

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the job of mass redirect or also know as mass [301](http://pcmate.org/mass-301-redirect) redirect. What it does, it transfers any URL to the destinied place where you want. It can be done via different ways, such as plugins if you use wordpress or any other cms, php with a code etc.