# How can I have a naked domain reroute to another specific domain?

Tags: redirect

I have a naked domain dpau.org that I want to reroute to the subdomain www.dpau.org including any complicated paths that follow the request? For example, I want someone who navigates to http://dpau.org/artists to be redirected to http://www.dpau.org/artists

The reason for this is somewhat complicated, but basically I use google hosted sites and have all our sites mapped to www.dpau.org/whatev but obviously people will ignore this www subdomain and I need something to correct for this ignorance.

Any help is enormously appreciated and will help the at-risk teens who come to our school in downtown Denver to learn the arts for free. Thanks Stackers!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add www to url and redirect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683378/how-to-add-www-to-url-and-redirect)

Comment: What is the server? Apache? IIS?

Comment: Apache duplicate (an answer to that question also shows the reverse): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see now you're using Google Sites. It all depends on what DNS host you use.

The relevant help page is here:
http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=61057